# How to import floating point data in form of 1.165e+10 into postgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, types, floating-point

I had checked data type on PostgreSQL website about this issue already but i didn't find any data type that match with a format like `1.0495e+5`

Is there any data type that match with this format?

If don't have

How can i convert `1.0495e+5` to `104950`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry, i was too hurry. It was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a problem? PostgreSQL 9.3

```
postgres=# select 1.0495e+5;
 ?column? 
──────────
   104950
(1 row)
```